# How to display emoji using angularJs?

Tags: html, angularjs, emoji

I am new to angularjs and I am using **"emoji-min.js"** and **"emoji-min.css"** to display the *emoji* in text field.

But I am not able to display. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype>
<html ng-app = "app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="emoji.min.css">
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="emoji.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           var app =  angular.module("app", ["emoji"])
            app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = "String including Emoji codes :smiley:";
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <textarea ng-model="message"></textarea>
        <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="message | emoji"></p>
        <pre>{{ message }}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please tell where I am going wrong.

Comment: can you add fiddle or something?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/madhur/angular-emoji-popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ng-bind-html to work, you need to have **ngSanitize** module injected in your app.

checkout [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)